# $localStorageProvider and setKeyPrefix within angular.injector

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, ng-storage

i wanted to configure the prefix of ngstorage within my pre-bootstrapping angular.injector.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    var
        initInjector = angular.injector(['ng', 'ngStorage']),
        $http = initInjector.get('$http'),
        $localStorage = initInjector.get('$localStorage'),
        $localStorageProvider = initInjector.get('$localStorageProvider'),
        storage = $localStorage.$default({
            configuration: {},
            configurationExpireDate: new Date()
        })
    ;
    // initInjector.config(function () { $localStorageProvider.setKeyPrefix('CT'); }); // not working
    $localStorageProvider.setKeyPrefix('CT'); // not working, too
}
```

So maybe you know how to configure the ngstorage prefix before the "real" app is bootstrapped programmatically.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What error is it throwing?

Answer (score 0):

For eg if,

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

You can use myApp.run(function() {

// Your code here. It will be executed before bootstrapping

});

Comment: Yes but I need to do a $http call before the app is bootstrapped and that's not working, because if I do this in the `.run()` it will execute the app before the call has finished.

Comment: hope this link will help, https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2014/10/22/asynchronously-bootstrapping-angularjs-applications-with-server-side-data

Comment: Refer this section 'Fetching the Required Data from the Server' from the above link.

Comment: -.- I'm used this tutorial @Ranjith S but the problem is that I need a `.config` or `.run` on the `angular.injector`... So that I can configure the prefix of `$localStorageProvider`. The call with $http is no problem! But I can't use the configure then...